# scala parallel set recursive value needs type

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, par

I have a code from 'Scala in depth' that works in interactive editor:

```
(1 to 1000).par map { _ => Thread.currentThread.toString } toSet
```

This prints a set with threads that were used for this parallel operation. All works great and a result type is ParSet[String]

But then I try to use it in a code and I have this:

```
val pthr = (1 to 1000).par map { _ => Thread.currentThread.toString } toSet
//val x = pthr.toSet
println("thread = " + pthr)
```

This throws: " error: recursive value pthr needs type" in println line. Another observation is when I uncomment second line everything works fine and a result is ParSet().

What is going on here? What is a type of variable "pthr"?

Comment: Use it with dots , no spaces and ... problem solved

Comment: What do you mean, "This throws: " error: recursive value pthr needs type"?  Are you saying you are getting an exception being thrown as a result of executing that code, or are you saying that the compiler is "throwing" such an error?

Answer (score 0):

The `println` method expects a string and you've provided a string with a `+` operator to pthr. In order to convert pthr to a string, the compiler needs to know which type it is. You haven't provided a type in your declaration of pthr but instead let it be inferred. For whatever reason, the inference isn't working so the compiler is requesting an explicit type declaration. You could simply do this:

```
val pthr : Set[String] = (1 to 1000).par map { _ => Thread.currentThread.toString } toSet
```

and that should take care of it.

However, I cannot reproduce your results with Scala 2.11.2. I get:

```
scala> val pthr = (1 to 1000).par map { _ => Thread.currentThread.toString } toSet
<console>:7: warning: postfix operator toSet should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scala docs for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
       val pthr = (1 to 1000).par map { _ => Thread.currentThread.toString } toSet
                                                                             ^
pthr: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSet[String] = ParSet(Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-27,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-23,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-21,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-17,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-31,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25,5,main])

scala> println("thread = " + pthr)
thread = ParSet(Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-13,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-27,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-23,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-21,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-17,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-31,5,main], Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25,5,main])
```

Other than the use of the `toSet` method as a postFix operator, there's nothing wrong with the code and it compiles and executes correctly. Perhaps you should check your version of the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know this works in interactive `scala` but doesn't during compilation by `scalac`.

Okay here is minimalistic example let's call this file "**`test.scala`**":

```
//test.scala
object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val pthr = (1 to 1000).par map { _ => Thread.currentThread.toString } toSet
    println("thread = " + pthr)
  }
}
```

Now let's execute in terminal:

```
-> scalac test.scala                                              
test.scala:5: error: recursive value pthr needs type
println("thread = " + pthr)
                      ^
one error found

-> scalac -version                             
Scala compiler version 2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

So again I have this issue only during compilation with `scalac`.

And when I add a type to pthr (`val pthr: Set[String] = ...`) then an error is:

```
test.scala:4: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: Set[String]
    val pthr:Set[String] = (1 to 1000).par map { _ => Thread.currentThread.toString } toSet
                                                                                  ^
one error found
```

No idea what is going on :/

BTW. this is the exact code copied from "Depth in scala" page 205.